# Numpy Array from Pandas Series

Tags: pandas, dataframe, numpy, series

I have a Data frame in which one column is the sequence of numbers like below
[Here's the pandas series with numpy values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/swy2u.png)
Now I want to read as (118,12) numpy array of type uint8, how can I do this because to_numpy() method converts it to object..

Comment: `to_numpy` isn't converting it.  That column is object dtype with a separate array in each cell. `np.stack` may be able to create a 2d array from it.  Or `vstack`

Comment: Can u plz tell how

Comment: read the duplicate